# How to properly set a parent state within a react datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an entity with a date that within a datepicker component I need to change for a new date. To do that I'm ussing a popup. The popup work flawlessly if I click the datepicker and handle the change with the function `this.props.handleDateChange` but if the users types in the date with the keyboard I can't catch the new date and modify my parent state with the value in my datepicker `this.props.myEntityCurrentDate`. How can I achieve this?

I have the following HOC that corresponds to an popup in react. It receives a body and a footer.

```
const createPopup = (Body, Footer) => {
    class Popup extends React.PureComponent {
        render() {
            return <div className='popup-react'>
                    <div className='popup-react-content'>

                        <div>

                            <div>
                                <span>{this.props.title}</span>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <Body {...this.props} />
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <Footer {...this.props} />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>;
        }
    }
    return Popup;
}
```

And I create the following body and footer for the desired page

```
class PopupBody extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return <div>
                   <DatePicker
                       dateFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
                       value={this.props.myEntityCurrentDate}
                       onChange={this.props.handleDateChange}
                       />
               </div>;
    }
}

class PopupFooter extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return <div>
                   <button type="button">
                       <span onClick={() => this.props.handleSubmit(this.props.myEntityId)}>Accept</span>
                   </button>
                   <button type="button" onClick={this.props.closePopup}>
                       <span className='ui-button-text'>Cancel</span>
                   </button>
               </div>;
    }
}

const Popup = createPopup(PopupBody, PopupFooter);
```

The component that will make use of those components and render the popup is the following:

```
class MyEntity extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {           
            showPopup: true,
            newDate: null,
            errors: []
        };

        //bind of this


        };
    }

    handlePopupDateChange(dueDate) {
        this.setState({
            newDate: dueDate,
            errors: []
        });
    }

    handlePopupSubmit(id) {
        var validations = {
            newDate: {
                presence: {
                    allowEmpty: false, message: " can't be empty"
                }
            }
        };

        validate(this.state, validations, () => this.submitPopupForm(id), this.renderPopupErrors);
    }

    submitPopupForm(id) {
        var vm = { Id: parseInt(id), DueDate: this.state.newDate ? this.state.newDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY") : null }

        this.props.apiClient.post('/api/MyEntity/Put/',
            vm,
            this.formPopupSucceeded,
            this.formPopupFailed);
    }

    formPopupSucceeded() {
        this.togglePopup();
        window.location.reload();
    }

    formPopupFailed(response) {
        this.togglePopup();
        this.renderPopupErrors([response.Message]);
    }

    renderPopupErrors(validationErrors) {
        this.togglePopup();
        this.setState({ errors: validationErrors });
    }

    togglePopup() {
        this.setState({
            showPopup: !this.state.showPopup,
            newDate: null,
        });
    }

    render() {
       return <div>
                    <If condition={this.state.showPopup}>
                       <Popup
                           title='My Popup Title'
                           closePopup={this.togglePopup}
                           myEntityCurrentDate={myMappedEntity.Date}
                           handleDateChange={this.handlePopupDateChange}
                           handleSubmit={this.handlePopupSubmit}
                           Date={this.state.newDate}
                           myEntityId={myMappedEntity.Id} />
                    </If>
               </div>;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think, when the user type with the keyboard you dont set the new value for your "myEntityCurrentDate" so you would need to to handle this case manually

Comment: @AndréGomes I thought that when the user types in a value it is being catch it in the `this.props` of the value that subsequently will update the `this.state.newDate`. Eventually I was wrong. Do you know how can I catch the user typing in event?

Comment: Like that i would say on your **handleDateChange**, but as i saw in the function you receive the date directly and not an event (i guess), do you use a librairy for the Datepicker ? if yes they probably give you some info about it (but its weird, **handleDateChange** should receive an event...)

Comment: not solving your solution but that might point to the right direction, try to do a `console.log(dueDate)` in your `handlePopupDateChange`, and see what is passed when a user types the date

Comment: @mokk `handlePopupDateChange` is working properly when the user clicks in the datepicker, the issue is when the user types in the date without clicking in the datepicker and submitting the popup — the state is not being modified

Comment: @Aoren can you print a console log of the onChange when you try to enter the date manually ?

Comment: just guessing, but I am suspecting that clicking on the datepicker probably sends a date to your `handlePopupDateChange` which works fine, but when typing, I would guess it sends a string which could be why it breaks as this string is not recognised as a proper date ?

Comment: @mokk if it is that he just need to create a new date with Date object

Comment: @Aoren otherwise if you haven't done it yet, install the react development tool for your browser, and inspect the components one by one before / after your submit to see what values are set in the props and state. That might help you identify exactly where the data starts to behave wrongly

Comment: mokk is right, clicking on the datepicker sends a date type to the `handlePopupDateChange` which is why it works, although I'm not sure if typing in the value sends a string. Let me check your suggestions.

Comment: @Aoren any luck ?

Comment: Still working on it, will update at the end of the day